# how to know if the current file in the buffer is a (.)dotfile using vimscript?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I changed vim backup directory to be stored on  `.backup` folder in my dotfiles local repo

`set undodir=$HOME/.dotfiles/backup//`.

it works well as expected but i want to separate actual dotfiles backups to be saved in a new directory named `dot-files` inside of `.backup`( `.backup/dot-files`)

eg: if the file is `.tmux.conf`, `.vimrc`, `.bashrc` etc.. it will be saved in the `backup/dot-files` but if it is an ordinary file just save it in the `backup` directory.

is this doable with vimscript?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve here. If you want backups for your dotfiles stored separately so it's easier to revert changes if you change your mind then you may be better off using a version control system such as Git to store your dotfiles. That way you'd be able to revert changes back as far as you like, while also being able to better examine the differences.

Comment: Sorry im not clear in my question, im already using git in a local repo named dotfiles ```~/Projects/dotfiles``` what i want is to store backup files in the subdirectory of dotfiles which is categorized as ```~/dotfiles/.backup/dot-files```(for files starting with (.) ) and ```~/dotfiles/.backup/```( for all files without (.))   Btw ```~/.backup``` is ignored in version control.. what i want is a separate backups for (.)files so i can easily find them when i need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test `expand('%:p')` against the directory you're looking for.

Check the help from `expand()`, from there, follow the link to the filename modifiers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. I'm on mobile right now I'll try this when I get to my PC